# Should Stack Exchange moderators automatically be meta.so moderators too?

Tags: discussion, moderators, stackexchange-2.0

I understand that currently moderators of any of the main sites are automatically made moderators of this site too. Once the various SE 2.0 sites progress out of beta and their permanent moderators are elected, this would suggest that those moderators would also get the same powers here. This could mean potentially hundreds of meta mods.

Should SE moderators be made meta.so moderators or should the status quo be maintained?

Comment: There are... A *lot* of moderators here already. You can't throw a brick around here without hitting a moderator or two. In their faces. Simultaneously. Packed cheek-to-cheek, *that's* how many moderators there are here.

Comment: I agree, hence the question. Jeff's response sums it up nicely and makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current plan is that only trilogy moderators are made moderators here on meta.so.

Because each new site has its own per-site meta (including Server Fault and Super User), that is no longer true.

The current list of meta.so moderators will probably be grandfathered in, but we won't add any more.

Comment: What's a 'trilogy mod' or a 'trilogy site'?

Comment: What do you mean by 'grandfathered in'?

Comment: @YatharthROCK A trilogy site is one of [SO], [SU] or [SF].

Comment: At some point - MSE mods are only employees, not trilogy mods so this answer is outdated. The question is closed so I can't really do much except comment, or mangle Jeff's answer so I'll do the former ;p

Answer (score 2):

Meta SO is a separate community. We talk about problems on StackOverflow and problems with the site system. We therefore elect moderators with the thought that they will be able to moderate conversation regarding that.

SE Site Moderators are elected with different responsibilities. SE Site Moderators are elected with the thought that they will be able to moderate conversation regarding their own individual topic.

SE Site Moderators are not elect to moderate the conversations that happen on MSO, and vice versa. Therefore the two should remain separate.

Besides, there would be too many chiefs.

Comment: My point is that all existing SU/SF/SO moderators are also meta moderators, so if the precedent was followed the SE moderators would be too. I think that's unwise and wanted to understand what the position was. I'm glad to see they've thought about this and it won't be the case