# Are the (soon to be) newly elected Stack Overflow moderators Meta Stack Mods?

Tags: discussion, election

As it seems that Meta Stack Overflow is a bit different from all of the other Meta sites, I was wondering if the election of moderators is the same.  With other sites, if a Mod is elected he/she is also the Meta Mod as well.  Is this the same with Stack Overflow Mod's?  If so, I find that this *may* be a bit concerning as Meta Stackoverflow doesn't just deal with the Stackoverflow site, but can be a resource for all other sites as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before Stack Exchange the rule was that every trilogy moderator is also a Meta Stack Overflow moderator. However, I do recall a conversation recently where it was mentioned that Meta Stack Overflow now has too many moderators.

I do however believe that Stack Overflow moderators at least should have moderator rights on MSO, as it does deal with their domain, and predominately questions about Stack Overflow itself, and its users.

[Jeff said something about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59262/should-stack-exchange-moderators-automatically-be-meta-so-moderators-too/59264#59264), although it is a little difficult to decipher exactly what that answer implies.

Comment: Jeff said something about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59262/should-stack-exchange-moderators-automatically-be-meta-so-moderators-too/59264#59264) at least, although I had a little trouble deciphering exactly what that answer implies.

Answer (score 1):

At least all moderators of the trilogy sites are also mod on MSO.

Comment: not anymore....